# GCP k8s - from a cluster to another cluster with mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

On a GCP project, I have a K8s architecture including 2 clusters.

- one cluster for microservices
- one cluster for mongodb

I have tested my mongodb cluster from inside and ensured that its works as intended. 
What I'm trying to do now is to connect from a pod on another cluster. I'have exposed the mongo service using a node port on the **mongodb** cluster:

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    labels:
      name: mongo
    name: mongodb-service
    annotations:
        cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  spec:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    ports:
    - name: port-mongodb
      port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 27017
    selector:
      role: mongo
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: NodePort
```

With the IP of my **mongodb** cluster:

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://35.240.47.130
    name: gke_myproject_europe-west1-b_mongodb
```

And the port of my NodePort:

```
mongodb-service   NodePort    10.3.248.249   <none>        27017:32752/TCP   6m
```

From a new pod with python into the **microservice** cluster (exactly the same I used to test the mongodb cluster from inside), I execute the following python script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://login:pass@35.240.47.130:32752")
database = client["testdb"]
collection = database["testcollection"]
inserted_id = 
collection.insert_one({"moonlight":"sonata"}).inserted_id
```

The result is always an error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo:32752: timed out
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

Additionally, here is some nslookup tests from the **microservices** cluster. First, I check the mongodb NodePort service IP

```
root@pybbox-55bdc76ddb-nw5gm:/# nslookup 10.3.248.249
Server:     10.35.240.10
Address:    10.35.240.10#53

** server can't find 249.248.3.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Also, I check if the cluster see the other using the cluster IP.

```
root@pybbox-55bdc76ddb-nw5gm:/# nslookup 35.240.47.130 
Server:     10.35.240.10
Address:    10.35.240.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
130.47.240.35.in-addr.arpa  name = 130.47.240.35.bc.googleusercontent.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: You're likely using a wrong IP. The one you're using to connect (35.240.47.130) looks like external IP, however, you're trying to connect to internal load balancer. Could you try using the IP of the NodePort service, which is of the internal load balancer (10.3.248.249)?

Comment: I did some tests from the same cluster as mongodb according to your remark. The result is into the UPDATE section of my post.

Comment: You mentioned this is GCP have you applied firewall rules so those Clusters can see each other? Or by clusters you are referring to 2 nodes inside one cluster?

Comment: @Crou I have done some nslookup tests and edited, UPDATE 2, my post. There is not any firewall rule configured.

Comment: nslookup is not a good tool here, check using telnet on mongodb port.

Comment: That seems to be a problem between the clusters even before reaching the mongo ports. Until now, I cannot succeed to connect to the second cluster: **mongodb-service.default.svc.mongodb**

Comment: Please provide output of `kubectl get po` and `kubectl get no`